# Delphi app crashing outside debugger but not inside

Tags: delphi

Our DUnit project is crashing on exit. It crashes if "Run Without Debugging", but *doesn't* crash if I Run *inside* the debugger.

If I attach the debugger to the process after starting it, it does not crash on exit.

I suspected a problem in finalization, so I put print statements in all the finalization code I suspected was running. This turned up nothing useful. Finalization for one of our low level Units (with no dependencies on any non-system Units) is running correctly. So it still *could* be finalization, but it may not be.

The crash produces this dialog:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: MCLTesting.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4eb07b50
  Fault Module Name:    kernel32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.0.6001.18215
  Fault Module Timestamp:   49953395
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000bf395
  OS Version:   6.0.6001.2.1.0.256.6
  Locale ID:    3081
  Additional Information 1: b37c
  Additional Information 2: 2a7328d8bb40c81c93b4b5f46adb8e10
  Additional Information 3: b37c
  Additional Information 4: 2a7328d8bb40c81c93b4b5f46adb8e10
```

"Exception Code: c0000005" Does that mean anything?

The main clue I have is the fact that it doesn't crash in the debugger. Has anyone seen that before?

Comment: What happens if you start without a debugger and attach it while the program is running?

Comment: The exception 0xC0000005 means that the application accessed memory that it does not own. For example, an attempt to read past the end of an allocated buffer could cause this.  It is quite possible that when run in the context of a debugger, the memory layout changes and the memory after the theoretical buffer is still owned by the process.

Comment: So for example if an object was accessed after it was freed?

Comment: This is typically an exception that happens after the Delphi RTL exception handler has unloaded; error `0xC0000005` is `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. It can also be an error caused by violating Data Execution Prevention (DEP). [MadExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) might be able to help track it down. It's free for non-commercial use (and definitely worth the expense if you can use it in your end-user apps), so you can use it for debugging problems like this one.

Comment: If no other method helps, try to comment out code, part by part, in order to get a clue, which part of it causes the crash. "Poor man's debugger", works everytime and everywhere. However, not for deadlocks, race conditions or other thread synchronization bugs.

Comment: @Sergiy Your suggestion worked in the end.

Comment: cool. What was the real reason, btw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally tracked this down.

The problem was indeed in a finalizer. A user exception was being thrown in a finalizer. The exception was not caught, and the exception itself was being leaked (The Exception and its string were not freed). It seems this memory leak was causing the crash? I'm not sure why I didn't notice this memory leak when I originally posted.

Catching the exception fixed the crash problem.

One interesting thing I found out is that even if an uncaught exception is thrown in a finalizer, subsequent Unit's finalizers will still be run. I was assuming that a problem in one finalizer would stop all subsequent finalizers from running.

The method I used to find the offending Unit was very simple; I removed all units from my project, then reintroduced Units one by one until I got the crash bug. Time consuming but it worked in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Exception code c0000005 is an access violation.  This usually means one of two things: either you're attempting to dereference a pointer or object reference that's set to **nil**, or you're working with corrupted memory.

The other pertinent piece of data in the error report is `Exception Offset: 000bf395`.  That tells you *where* the error is occurring.  Try looking up `f395` in your map file and see if you can't find a unit finalization that corresponds to that memory offset.  If so, that should give you a good idea as to what's going wrong.

Comment: The only occurence of "f395" is in a section titled: "Line numbers for Controls(Controls.pas) segment .text". Which I assume is not related to the offending unit? (see my answer)